# Hide MPMoviePlayerController while new video loads

Tags: iphone, ipad, hide, mpmovieplayercontroller, uiactivityindicatorview

I have an iPad app that has 4 buttons on the left side that corresponds to 4 different video clips. When a user taps the video they want to see, it appears on the right side. I am wanting it to appear to be loading (as if it were streaming over the internet). I added the UIActivityIndicator to the center of the black video frame and have a thread that pauses for 3 seconds. However, the player containing the previous video does not disappear. It just freezes on the last frame of the previous video for 3 seconds (hiding the activity indicator) and then the new video appears.

Any ideas on how to make the player temporarily be hidden? Thanks for any help. Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction) videoButton1{
   [player stop];
   [player release];

   [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

   NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video1" ofType:@"mov"];
   [self setupVideoPlayer:url];
}

-(void) setupVideoPlayer: (NSString *) url{
   player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url)];
   player.view.frame = CGRectMake(487, 205, 478, 320);

   [self.view addSubview:player.view];

   [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.0];
   self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

   [player play];
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to bump this thread. I still can't figure out why that after releasing the player, it still holds the last frame of the video through the "sleep" thread. The sleep command is even called after the player has loaded the new video, and just before the play command. Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the frame of your player to a View that you can make in IB or programmatically instead of doing a CGRectMake every time.

> self.player.view.frame =
> self.viewForMovie.bounds;
>
> self.player.view.autoresizingMask =
> UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
> UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

Then in your "videoButton1" you can set the alpha of the View to 0

> viewForMovie.alpha = 0;

And in your "setupVideoPlayer" you can change the alpha back to 1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I played around with what you said, the only thing now is that the video player doesn't auto play in the new movieView. The controls appear correctly, but I don't think it is detecting touches. Any more pointers?

Comment: I got it figured out. The problem was that I had the movie player in a new thread. Now I know how much apple doesn't like that. So in the new thread I used [NSThread sleepforTimeInterval:3.0]; // To appear to be loading. Then use the performSelectorOnMainThread method to actually load the video into the view. Thanks for the info Ricardo. You pointed me in the right direction.